# Customize CakePHP Test Suite Messages

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to confirm that, is this possible to customize Cakephp test suite(Unit Testing) message to our desired message on success & failed by default? It shows the following message

[image]

Now i want to customize time duration micro second to second by rounding function & also change Passed message to success OR my own message. How can i achieved this goal? 
Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `./lib/Cake/TestSuite/Reporter/CakeHtmlReporter.php` you can modify how the TestSuite reports stats.

I'm using a different version of CakePHP, but for me, Line 151 is this:

```
echo '<p><strong>Time:</strong> ' . $result->time() . ' seconds</p>';
```

You can take the `$result->time()` and run it through whatever PHP functions you want to get the output you're after. For that matter `$result` is set during your test cases is it not?